# Alamofire timeout url

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using the Alamofire Swift library

```
Alamofire.request
    (RestApiManager.sharedInstance.baseURL+"login?language="+lang, 
    method: .post, 
    parameters: requestDictionary, 
    encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody,
    headers: headers
    ).responseObject(keyPath: "") { (response: DataResponse<User>) in          
        let user = response.result.value
        print(user?.status)
        print(user?.message)             
}
```

So simply, I want to put a timeout of 60 seconds on every call I make.And i like to give a message connection timeout after 60 seconds. I also want to know, if there exists an internet connection or not. If it doesnt exist, I like to avoid calling alamofire.

Comment: Please don't include the answer in your question. If an answer solved your issue, mark the answer as accepted; you can also post your own answer if you resolved your problem yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Swift 3.0 / Alamofire 4.0 code to get an alamofireManager that has a 60 second timeout.
You need create a global variable for the request manager:

```
var alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance
```

And after configure the custom parameters:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 60 // seconds
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60
    self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

Comment: No more manager, shall use sessionmanager. I am using swift 3, but alamofire recent version.